# How can Newell Brands (NWL) have a positive EPS for the most recent quarter despite reporting negative earnings?

Tags: stocks, earnings-per-share

Currently looking at their [Yahoo! Finance page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NWL/financials?p=NWL). They have earnings of -$7.31 billion for 3Q2018, yet the EPS for Q3 is report as 0.81. Shouldn't the EPS be negative as well?

Comment: $7B is a pretty big number for a company I've never heard of....

Comment: @xyious I strongly suspect your employer is their number one customer. The company used to be called NewellRubbermaid until 2016, but they also own the Sharpie, Sunbeam, Rival, Crock-Pot, Oster, Mr. Coffee, Xacto brands and more.

Comment: Still, think about the sheer scale of that number. Less than 2000 companies even have revenues over $1B. Let alone losing $7B.

Comment: I checked against their quarterly earnings report and it is correct (it's due to a lot of reorganizing). But my question still remains.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking at, but on the balance sheet there seems to be an answer to your question.

In Q3/2018 Net Income is (54,400)
There is also a Non-Reoccurring revenue source (discounted operations) of 107,000

This resulted in Net Income Applicable to Shareholders of 53,300, and would result in a positive EPS.

Comment: Are those numbers you listed not for Q1/2018? I think for Q3/2018 the Net Income Applicable to Shareholders is (7,311,000).

Comment: Reocurring or recurring?